# В чем может быть причина NPE при настройке мультиязычности в Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

Использую Spring Boot + Spring Security.
Для реализации мультиязычности использую это решение - 
https://medium.com/i18n-and-l10n-resources-for-developers/database-stored-messages-for-i18n-in-spring-boot-11dc2ee5c1f7

Проблема следующая:
Обычно, Spring Security, если URL не существует или возникает исключение, то должен корректно его обработать. Например, если пароль пользователя введен неверно, то должен вернуть страницу с параметром ?authError. В принципе, до настройки мультиязычности по методу выше все работало.

Теперь, наблюдаю некий конфликт, когда Spring Security вместо обработки ошибки выбрасывает NPE

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at info.md7.freelance.tools.DBMessageSource.resolveCode(DBMessageSource.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.resolveCodeWithoutArguments(AbstractMessageSource.java:368) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessageInternal(AbstractMessageSource.java:212) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:141) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getMessage(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1310) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceAccessor.getMessage(MessageSourceAccessor.java:87) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:93) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:166) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:195) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:95) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:141) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_211]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_211]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_211]
```

Содержимое DBMessageSource

```
@Component("messageSource")
public class DBMessageSource extends AbstractMessageSource {

    @Autowired
    private TranslationRepository languageRepository;

    private static final String DEFAULT_LOCALE_CODE = "az";

    @Override
    protected MessageFormat resolveCode(String key, Locale locale) {
        Translation message = languageRepository.findByKeyAndLocale(key, locale.getLanguage());
        if (message == null) {
            message = languageRepository.findByKeyAndLocale(key, DEFAULT_LOCALE_CODE);
        }
        >>> return new MessageFormat(message.getContent(), locale);
    }

}
```

Это null

```
message.getContent()
```

Почему-то в метод resolveCode() передается в качестве key 
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials и соответственно ошибка 500.

Как устранить исключение? Что-то не пойму откуда ноги растут...

Готов дать доступ к BitBucket или к Github. Уже 2-й день бьюсь)))

Заранее спасибо за советы и за помощь!

P.S. Всех с наступающим!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В статье делается предположение что для языка по умолчанию для каждого элемента гарантированно есть перевод. Это не всегда так, особенно на старте разработки. Добавьте дополнительную проверку

```
   ...
   if(message == null || message.getContent() == null) {
      return null;
   }
   return new MessageFormat(message.getContent(), locale);
   ...
```

После чего, при возврате null, будут генерироваться строки-переводы вроде "??login.label_page_header_ru_RU??" и Вы легко сможете понять, для какого элемента и языка необходимо добавить перевод

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Добавление правка кода вышеуказанным способом  решило проблему. А при дебаге видно следующее: NPE - locale ru_RU (есть ли разница в ru или ru_RU?). message - null  key - AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials    Он почему-то пытается искать перевод для вышеуказанного ключа в БД...

Comment: >> есть ли разница в ru или ru_RU
Второе - это название локали. "ru_RU" обозначает язык+страну, в данном случае "Русский - Русский". На моей машине есть еще по крайней мере "ru_UA" - "Русский - Украинский", "uk_UA" - "Украинский - Украинский".

Comment: >> message - null key - AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials Он почему-то пытается искать перевод для вышеуказанного ключа в БД...
Это происходит потому, что на странице есть отображение stacktrace возникшего исключения с интернационализацией

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь, все стало ясно)